# Can't use rpg-module package

Tags: packages, miktex, texworks, modules

I'm trying to use this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/rpg-module
In TeXworks 0.6.7 and MiKTeX Console 4.9

Here's the document I'm trying to make:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rpg-module}
\begin{document}
First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.
\end{document}
```

And I'm getting the following error:
! LaTeX Error: File `rpg-module.sty' not found.

I installed rpg-module using MikTex Console's package manager.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE! It's a class so it should be loaded `\documentclass{rpg-module}`

Comment: @mbert Thanks. When I do that, I get the following error: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1640 \pgfutil@protected
                         \def\pgfmathprintnumber{%
?

Comment: Yes, the package does `\input{pgfmath.code}` which may have worked in 2016 but it seems some definitions were move around. Adding `\RequirePackage{pgfmath}` before `\documentclass` should fix that